# Phrase choice - phrase to describe exodus of meaningful celebrities from Australia

Tags: phrase-requests

Most meaningful socialites seem to leave Australia, leaving us with celebrity cooks and celebrity hairdressers. (eg Elle McPherson and Savage Garden going to London etc). What's the phrase to describe the exodus of meaningful celebrities from Australia?

Is this "post-colonial parochialism"? "First-world elitism?" Or is it just "Global Capitalism"?

Comment: Is this about English language? Or is it sociology?

Comment: If (after) you have decided what to call it and can express it in someway, we could start looking for a suitable word/ phrase for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need a phrase for this: "exodus of meaningful celebrities" is already perfect, with its strong hint of oxymoronicism spiced with biblical exaggeration.

Perhaps a "golgafrincham" is the word, although technically it's not quite correct.  But it doesnt hold a candle to the "meaningful celebrities" gag.

Comment: "golgafrincham" - that is hilarious...

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's *the vain drain*? Or *the cocaine drain*?

Comment: I'm so glad you picked up on the humour in the question...

Comment: Or *fame drain*?

Comment: I found another one on wikipedia: Cultural Cringe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_cringe "Cultural cringe, in cultural studies and social anthropology, is an internalized inferiority complex which causes people in a country to dismiss their own culture as inferior to the cultures of other countries. It is closely related, although not identical, to the concept of colonial mentality, and is often linked with the display of anti-intellectual attitudes towards thinkers, scientists and artists who originate from a colonial or post-colonial nation."

Answer (score 1):

Since the sentence you've constructed intends to contrast the behavior of Aussie's who've gained international notoriety and the behavior of Aussie's whose fame exists only within their homeland, it seems preferable to simply state your distinction on those terms. After all, since contrast is basic to your construction, calling one group meaningful implies that the other is not. And I doubt that's built in, really, to what you're meaning to convey.

Here's what it looks like you intend, if you'll allow for the split infinitive:

> As soon as mega-talented Aussies gain international fame, generally speaking, they seem content to abandon our shores and leave Australia in the trusty hands of celebrity hairdressers and celebrity cooks.

Beyond this, what you're asking for somewhat eludes me. Are you looking for a title, a phrase to use in *another* sentence referring back to this one, a replacement for the term meaningful socialites *in* this sentence, or, more broadly, just a way to talk about the phenomenon?

Comment: I was looking for a two or three word phrase that captured this idea. A reference or a pointer to the idea you have enunciated.